# How to make a dataframe into a case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Lots of documentations show that it's possible to go from a case class to a dataframe, but I haven't been able to find a good way of going from a dataframe to a case class.

Let's say I have a dataframe with 50 columns, but would like to select out about 5 columns and make it into a new table. I could approach it this way:

```
sqlContext.sql("select [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] from test").registerTempTable("newTable")
```

But the newTable will have some other columns like 6, 7 as a customized value (or 0 for now, but this column just doesn't exist in the test table).
To solve this, I tried to create a case class that looks like this:

```
case class newTable(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

In the end, I would want to extract column 1 through 5 from the test table, then input 6, 7 whatever I would like to. I just haven't found a good way of doing this.

Comment: I think all you need is `withColumn` after the select, to add new columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use like this:

```
dataframe.select($"1".as("1"), $"2".as("2"), $"3".as("3"), $"4".as("4"), $"5".as("5")).as[newTable]
```

Note :
  you should match the column name as the field name in your case class

Comment: How do I incorporate this with the case class I created?

Comment: Also, I'm getting an error with this:
error: overloaded method value as with alternatives:
  (alias: Symbol)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (alias: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 does not take type parameters

Comment: it because your case class and your name column dosnt match

Comment: I tried to match case class type with whatever is showing on console:
error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column, String, Int, Long, Long)

but still getting this error

Comment: ill recommend you to use sparkSession

Comment: ahh I have some other features that I'm using from Spark 1.5 and avoiding to upgrade to 2.0 just yet..

Comment: i think you should cause there`s a lot of new features in there that older version are not capable of .. :)

Comment: I will after I solve this problem!
Unfortunately, this isn't getting resolved for me :(
I reduced the number of the parameter to `case class newTable(a: String)`, and `df.select($"a".as("a")).as[newTable]` throws:
 `error: overloaded method value as with alternatives:
  (alias: Symbol)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (alias: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 does not take type parameters`

Comment: actually - it was simply resolved when I upgraded from 1.5 to 1.6.. thanks for the help!

Comment: its good to know that you solve it i think 1.5 doesnt support that feature :)